# Infinite loop when forcing SSL either in vhost or in security.yml/routing.yml

Tags: symfony, ssl, nginx, https

I am workling with Symphony 2.6 and Nginx 1.4. This question was already asked several times, but all of the provided answers or solutions doesn't work for me.

I want the New Linux Counter Project to be completely SSL only, but no matter if I set a redirect to port 443 in the vhost file of nginx or if I add required_channel https to the security.yml or if I add [https] to the routing.yml, everything results in an infinite loop when visiting the page.

Nevertheless, SSL is working without problems. When removing all redirects from the vhost file and https stuff from the security.yml and the routing.yml, everything works and you can visit for example: https://www.linuxcounter.net/login without any problems.

**This is the vhost file *without* the forcing to SSL:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.linuxcounter.net api.linuxcounter.net linuxcounter.net;
    root /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/web;

    client_max_body_size 128M;

    location ~ ^/update\.php(/|$) {
        root /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/web;
        fastcgi_pass php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~* ^/user/([0-9]+)\.html$ {
        root /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/web;
        rewrite /user/([0-9]+)\.html /user/$1 last;
        internal;
    }

    location ~* /(cert|mcert)/[0-9]+\.png$ {
    root /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/web;
        rewrite /(cert|mcert)/[0-9]+\.png /app.php last;
    expires -1;
    add_header Cache-Control private;
    }

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    internal;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css)$ {
        root /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/web;
        expires 30d;
    }

    error_log /LOGS/www.linuxcounter.net_error_log;
    access_log /LOGS/www.linuxcounter.net_access_log;
}

server {
    listen 443 default;
    server_name www.linuxcounter.net api.linuxcounter.net linuxcounter.net;
    root /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/web;

    client_max_body_size 128M;

    ssl                     on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/2015-04-02-www.linuxcounter.net-cert-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/2015-04-02-www.linuxcounter.net.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!kEDH;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location ~ ^/update\.php(/|$) {
        root /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/web;
        fastcgi_pass php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~* /(cert|mcert)/[0-9]+\.png$ {
        root /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/web;
        rewrite /(cert|mcert)/[0-9]+\.png /app.php last;
        expires -1;
        add_header Cache-Control private;
    }

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        internal;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css)$ {
        root /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/web;
        expires 30d;
    }

    error_log /LOGS/www.linuxcounter.net_error_log;
    access_log /LOGS/www.linuxcounter.net_access_log;
}
```

**And this is the vhost file *WITH* forcing to SSL:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.linuxcounter.net api.linuxcounter.net linuxcounter.net;
    root /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/web;
    return 301 https://www.linuxcounter.net$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.linuxcounter.net api.linuxcounter.net linuxcounter.net;
    root /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/web;

    client_max_body_size 512M;

    # ssl                     on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/2015-04-02-www.linuxcounter.net-cert-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/2015-04-02-www.linuxcounter.net.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!kEDH;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location ~ ^/update\.php(/|$) {
        root /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/web;
        fastcgi_pass php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~* /(cert|mcert)/[0-9]+\.png$ {
        root /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/web;
        rewrite /(cert|mcert)/[0-9]+\.png /app.php last;
        expires -1;
        add_header Cache-Control private;
    }

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        internal;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css)$ {
        root /srv/www.linuxcounter.net/web;
        expires 30d;
    }

    error_log /LOGS/www.linuxcounter.net_error_log;
    access_log /LOGS/www.linuxcounter.net_access_log;
}
```

As soon as I replace the vhost file with the one that has the redirection to SSL on port 80, then I get only infinite loops on all pages, links or routes.

So when browsing to https://www.linuxcounter.net/login, then /login gets reloaded with 301 redirections 15 or 20 times until the error message of infinite loop  appears.

But with the first vhost file, the whole page is working with https:// without problems.

**Here is my routing.yml:**

```
syw_front_main:
    resource: "@SywFrontMainBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    host:     %base_host%

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
    host:     %base_host%

easy_admin_bundle:
    resource: "@EasyAdminBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /admin
    host:     %base_host%

shtumi_useful:
    resource: '@ShtumiUsefulBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml'
    host:     %base_host%

blade_tester_light_news_bundle:
    resource: "@BladeTesterLightNewsBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /news
    host:     %base_host%

syw_front_api:
    resource: "@SywFrontApiBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    host:     %api_host%
```

**And this is my security.yml:**

```
# you can read more about security in the related section of the documentation
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
        # in_memory:
        #     memory:
        #         users:
        #             user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
        #             admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

    # the main part of the security, where you can set up firewalls
    # for specific sections of your app
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            form_login:
                # login success redirecting options (read further below)
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path:            fos_user_profile_show
                use_referer:                    true
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
            form_login:
                # login success redirecting options (read further below)
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path:            fos_user_profile_show
                use_referer:                    true

    # with these settings you can restrict or allow access for different parts
    # of your application based on roles, ip, host or methods
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: /admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Everything seems to be quiet normal to me....

But I don't get it to work.

**So, what I want is:**

if someone visits http://*linuxcounter.net, then he should get redirected with 301 to https://*linuxcounter.net

Comment: Okay... I've now tested my actual vhost file with the forcing to SSL on another subdomain with just a simple index.php containing one simple echo.
That works like a charm... so the problem MUST be in symfony somewhere...

Comment: Now I've tried it locally with a self signed certificate AND the symfony application of the linuxcounter. Since everything is in git and deployed automatically, the sources are identical.

Locally, everything works like a charm... the redirect when visiting http://... is working and only once, then I can browse the page on https://... as it should be... without any problems.

Then I've push this configuration to the live server, activated the same vhost file and restarted the server... and... infinite loops...

I give up... since there seems to be nobody who wants or can help me... I'm lost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... after many hours of trying and testing, I now came across with a solution that isn't very optimal, but it is working.

I'm now simply doing a redirect on the top of the /app.php of Symfony:

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"] == "http") {
    $redir = "Location: https://www.linuxcounter.net" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    header($redir);
    exit();
}
```

this works and doesn't produce any infinite loops.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use symfony as it's meant to be used?

1. set scheme to https (only) in your routes http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/scheme.html (easiest way is to define the scheme once in the routing.yml and then import e.g. https_routing.yml which gets scheme inherited for all routes).
2. tell symfony the correct headers http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/trusting_proxies.html#configuring-header-names

I use that setup in many projects. Right now I'm not 100% if redirection works without any other settings, but I can look it up tomorrow, if not. I think that should work, try it.

Comment: I've already tried this at first with no success. Anyways, the way I'm doing it now works like a charm and that is the most important thing for me.